# Scrapy redirects to logout before data is scraped

Tags: python, python-3.x, scrapy

The title might be a bit confusing but let me explain some more. I'm trying to build a simple scraper using scrapy to scrape a banking website for some automated budgeting. So far it seems that I can get logged in but then immediately after I get logged out without getting the data I need. Here's some text from my terminal:

```
1. 2018-03-27 00:56:56 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <POST 
   https://www.bank.org/signin-page.html> (referer: 
   https://www.bank.org/signin-page.html)
2. 2018-03-27 00:56:56 [LOG] INFO: LOGIN ATTEMPT SUCCESSFUL
3. 2018-03-27 00:56:56 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (404) <GET 
   https://www.bankonline.org/robots.txt> (referer: None)
4. 2018-03-27 00:56:56 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: 
   Redirecting (302) to <GET https://www.bankonline.org/tob/live/usp- 
   core/app/logout?reason=logout> from <GET 
   https://www.bankonline.org/tob/live/usp-core/app/home>
5. 2018-03-27 00:56:56 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET 
   https://www.bankonline.org/tob/live/usp-core/app/logout? 
   reason=logout> (referer: https://www.bank.org/signin-page.html)
6. 2018-03-27 00:56:56 [LOG] INFO: VISITED 
   https://www.bankonline.org/tob/live/usp-core/app/logout? 
   reason=logout
7. 2018-03-27 00:56:57 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider 
   (finished)
```

Line 4 is where it starts to redirect me. Here's my code:

```
import scrapy
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger('LOG')
USERNAME = 'user'
PASSWORD = 'pass'

class Budget_Bank(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "Budget_Bank"
    login_url = 'https://www.bank.org/signin-page.html'
    start_urls = ['https://www.bank.org/signin-page.html']

    def parse(self, response):
        yield scrapy.FormRequest(url=self.login_url,
                                 formdata={'username': USERNAME,
                                           'password': PASSWORD},
                                 callback=self.login_test)


    def login_test(self, response):
        if 'errors' in response.text:
            logger.warning("LOGIN ATTEMPT FAILED")
            return
        else:
            logger.info("LOGIN ATTEMPT SUCCESSFUL")
            yield scrapy.Request('https://www.bankonline.org'
                                 '/tob/live/usp-core/app/home',
                                 callback=self.parse_number)


    def parse_number(self, response):
        logger.info("VISITED %s", response.url)
        for number in response.css('div._1qtcLoK1d4PZmeghcgyE2K'):
            yield {
                'num': number.css('span.formattedMoney_balanceBZozG-'         
                                  ...::text').extract_first(),
            }
```

I'm so far just trying to get a single number from the site to test whether or not I can actually retrieve data. My login_test returns that I am logging in correctly, but instead of continuing on to the main page it redirects me to logout. I've omitted some info such as my username and password for obvious reasons, and also I changed the websites name. Some help would be much appreciated.

Comment: @Umair What's wrong with scraping a baking website? :D

Answer (score 0):

You are redirected to logout because it detects that you are a robot.

```
3. 2018-03-27 00:56:56 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (404) <GET 
   https://www.bankonline.org/robots.txt> (referer: None)
```

You can try to set `ROBOTSTXT_OBEY` to `False`

For more information see the [Doc](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#robotstxt-obey)